# oplrun: error while loading shared libraries: liboplnl1.so.12

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, cplex, shared-objects, opl

I'm trying to run Cplex from terminal command line in Ubuntu. When I execut
`/oplrun/path$ ./oplrun` I get the following error.

`./oplrun: error while loading shared libraries: liboplnl1.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How can I fix it?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed the command:
`/oplrun/path$ ldd oplrun`

and I found out there were two dependencies including liboplnl1.so.12 that were "not found" although they existed in the same path as oplrun. So, I copied the tow files to the path in which other dependencies existed. Now, if I run the `/oplrun/path$ ldd oplrun` command the so file is found at the address where I copied them:

`liboplnl1.so.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liboplnl1.so.12 (0x00007fa0db5bc000)`

Now, oplrun can be executed from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In CPLEX documentation

```
Linux platforms

Only the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is needed to point to the shared libraries of the CPLEX Studio distribution.

<Install_dir>/opl/bin/x86-64_linux
```

Comment: It could work. I saw your answer after I tried the other solution. Thank you for your answer.